# How did I uninstall KDE in 13.04?

Tags: 13.04, uninstall, kde, dependencies, desktop-environments

I wanted to uninstall `kde-standard` package (not confused with `kubuntu-desktop`) and all of KDE-related packages in 13.04. Seems `lightdm` shows too many desktops (because I installed lot of DEs) so Unity desktop selection gone off-screen. My selection is to uninstalls one of DEs I have.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.  Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove kde-standard
```

Also to clean the list, go to `/usr/share/xsessions/`, and delete the ones that you want.  **Keep in mind this will only remove the DE from the list**.

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo apt-get install -y ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

this works for me

Comment: This works only if you were using a **non-default** third-party repository for KDE.